# Subtract values of two cells relative to a cell, without directly referencing them

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to create the following table:

| Value | Difference to previous row |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 80 | 60 |

I would like the formula to be generic, without referencing any cells directly.

The following formula works:

```
=TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN() - 1)),"####.#") - TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1,COLUMN() - 1)),"####.#")
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify or shorten it (without using macros).

Comment: `TEXT()-TEXT()`? Why not just `INDIRECT()-INDIRECT()`? Or switch [**Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Formula - Formula syntax**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01060900.html) to **Excel R1C1** and use `=RC[-1]-R[-1]C[-1]` - *without referencing any cells directly*. I wonder where you get this fantasy? Why don't you like direct addressing? It's so easy `=A3-A2`!

Comment: @JohnSUN direct can be very dangerous referencing a previous row for example. If you delete, copy, move formulas, or cells down or up, you're then "never" sure if the formula =A3-A2 is still correct, it may be =A7-A5 now... And you've to check or correct the formula in all lines. In short, indirect is definitely what I'd use in this case.

Comment: The formula was copied from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/offset-from-current-cell.314030. I've removed `TEXT`, thanks. Are there any disadvantages to switching to R1C1 syntax? As for it being a "fantasy", I find that funny, and a little sad. What a boring fantasy. I was simply aiming for what Sylvain mentioned - that I could copy cells with generic formulas around without breaking anything. Easy != better.

Comment: One disadvantage of R1C1 syntax would be if someone else has to maintain the spreadsheet, they might not want to work with it. Also, you're stuck with that syntax for the entire spreadsheet, when maybe you only need this for the table and not for other places.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at JohnSUN's comment and answer, I discovered that the following works even if R1C1 notation isn't set. Go to *Sheet > Named Ranges and Expressions > Define* and specify name `thisCell` with expression `INDIRECT("RC";0)`.

Now, this does the same as your original formula:

```
=OFFSET(thisCell;0;-1) - OFFSET(thisCell;-1;-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you will accept this suggestion as an answer, but it's worth a try.

Place the cursor in cell **B3**. Choose **Sheet - Named Ranges and Expressions - Define** or just press [**Ctrl+F3**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04070100.html). Click the **Add** button here

Set a name. Any. You can write "abracadabra" or "Alohomora" or "AvadaKedavra"... But it's better if the name is meaningful - like "NextDifference".

Write down the formula. Just use addressing relative to the current cell (remember we highlighted B3 now?)

`=A3-A2`

[image: Add named formula]

Save this new name (**Add** and **OK**)

Are you still in cell **B3**? Write here the formula `=NextDifference`.

Is the result as expected? Okay, so you didn't make a mistake anywhere. (Otherwise, repeat this steps carefully)

Stretch cell **B3** down. See? Each cell contains the same formula without direct addressing, just like you wanted. Select one of the cells, for example, **B7** and press **CTRL+F3** again. See? For this cell, the name `NextDifference` contains the formula `A7-A6`

And now the main trick for the sake of which we started all this. Delete an arbitrary number of rows from the table, move them to another location, sort the table - the `=NextDifference` formula will work and give correct results. (Of course, you can break this if you remove the topmost rows - in this case you can get a **#REF!** error. But the formula you gave will do the same, right?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both approaches seem good to me, so I'll leave them unaccepted (but upvoted) for now, until I get more experience with each one.